# Serializar y deserializar automaticamente objetos que heredan de otros en un ajax request - ASP.NET Core

Tags: ajax, json, asp.net-core

Estoy intentado crear un **AJAX request** que envie un objeto (el cual he llamado `MainObject`) al servidor **Asp.Net CORE**. El problema es que este objeto contiene otro el cual hereda de un objeto base (`NestedObject` hereda de `BaseObject`).

Entonces, cuando envio el objeto, el método del controller es llamado y en lugar de recibir el `MainObject` con un `NestedObject` como parámetro, recibo un `MainObject` con el `BaseObject`. Es decir, como que no sabe que ese objeto no es de la clase base sino del que hereda. He probado a añadir la propiedad `$type` al objeto pero tampoco ha funcionado.

Alguien tiene alguna idea de como solucionar este problema? Gracias.

**Clases**

```
class BaseObject
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}

class NestedObject : BaseObject
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}

class MainObject 
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public BaseObject Item { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<MainObject> CreateObject(MainObject mainObject)
{
    if (mainObject.Item is NestedObject) {
        NestedObject nestedObject = mainObject.Item as NestedObject;
        string property1 = nestedObject.Property1;
        string property2 = nestedObject.Property2;
    }
    return mainObject;
}
```

**Ajax Request**

```
function SendRequest() {
     var mainObject = {
         Id = '1'
     };
     var nestedObject = new NestedObject() {
         Id = '1'
         Property1 = 'A',
         Property2 = 'B'
     };
     mainObject.Item = nestedObject;
     $.ajax({
         url: document.location.origin + '/Test/CreateObject',
         type: 'POST',
         data: {
             mainObject: mainObject
         },
         dataType: 'json',
         success: function() {
             console.log('fine');
         },
         error: function(e) {
             console.log('error');
         },
         complete: () => {
             console.log('complete');
         }
     });
}
```

**StartUp de la web AspNet CORE**

En el startup he definido que controle los objetos heredados. Es la propiedad `TypeNameHandling`.

```
services.AddMvc()
    .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
    .AddJsonOptions((options) =>
    {
        options.SerializerSettings.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All;
        options.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
        options.SerializerSettings.MaxDepth = null;
    });
```

Comment: En tu class MainObject estas indicando que Item va ser del tipo BaseObject, no NestedObject que es lo que queres recibir, es correcto esto?

Comment: @cjara Sí, pq tengo diferentes objetos que heredan de BaseObject. En el controller quiero ver si es de un tipo o de otro para realizar diferentes acciones. Esto en mi WebAPI me devuelve correctamente el objeto heredado, o sea NestedObject. Ahora estoy intentando que tmb funcione en la web y que envie correctamente los datos entre la Web ASP.NET y el cliente javascript para luego enviarlos a la WebAPI.

Answer (score 0):

En principio comentarte que es una muy buena pregunta, ya que es una de estas cosas nunca nos planteamos y existe una alta probabilidad de encontrar un problema así en un entorno productivo real.

Lo que intentas hacer **no se puede hacer** con el sistema de **Binding** que trae por defecto ASP.NET Core MVC. Esto es debido a que las estructuras de Modelo **polimórficas** o con **herencia**, no son interpretadas por el **Binding** por defecto.

En tu caso, debes crearte lo se se llama un **Model Binder personalizado** y aplicarlo al Modelo que quieres interpretar `MainObject`.

Para esto debes crear las clases personalizadas de Binding, que implementen las Interfaces `IModelBinder` y `IModelBinderProvider`. Sería algo así:

```
public class MyModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
   public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
   {
      // Aqui el código de Binding
   }
}

public class MyBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
       // Aqui el código de Binding
    }
}
```

Luego registrárlas como servicios en el `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddMvc(op => op.ModelBinderProviders.Insert(0, new 
MyBinderProvider()));
```

Y aplicar el nuevo **Binder personalizado** al Modelo que quieras analizar:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<MainObject> CreateObject([ModelBinder(typeof(MyModelBinder))] MainObject mainObject)
{
    if (mainObject.Item is NestedObject) {
       NestedObject nestedObject = mainObject.Item as NestedObject;
       string property1 = nestedObject.Property1;
       string property2 = nestedObject.Property2;
     }
     return mainObject; 
 }
```

Este es el trabajo que deberás hacer para solucionar tu problema.

Existen muchos enlaces en Stack Overflow Inglés para este mismo problema, te dejo algunos.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46414705/custom-model-binder-in-asp-net-core-for-sub-classes

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7222533/polymorphic-model-binding

Por otra parte, indicarte también que tienes mal construido el código JavaScript donde construyes los Modelos de datos, realmente no se como te puede funcionar así:

El código correcto sería así:

```
var mainObject = {
     Id : '1'
 };

 var nestedObject = {
     Id : '1',
     Property1 : 'A',
     Property2 : 'B'
};

 mainObject.Item = nestedObject;
```